# How to implement an interface

Tags: java, arrays, methods, interface, abstract-class

I have a populate interface that will be getting the current population, setting the population and increasing the population. I have a main that has my planets set in an array list so now what I need to do is to implement the code that will help me to increase the population of that planet based on that planets methods. Here is the population interface.

```
/**
 * This interface models the behavior of planets when travelers arrive 
 * and when they try to leave.
 * @author 
 *
 */
public interface Populate {

/**
 * Get the current population of the planet
 * @return the current population of the planet
 * @throws Exception if the value of the currentPopulation is none of your business
 */
public int getCurrentPopulation() throws Exception;
/**
 * Initialize the current population to a value
 * @param currentPopulation The value to initialize to
 * @return The new value of the current population, will be currentPopulation
 * @throws Exception if the value of the currentPopulation argument is negative
 */
public int setCurrentPopulation(int currentPopulation) throws Exception;
/***
 * Increase the population of the planet as travelers arrive.
 * @param populationIncrease The amount to increase the current population. Can be negative.
 * @return The new current population
 */
public int IncreasePopulation(int populationIncrease);

}
```

Here is the main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //this class will run calculations for planets

    ArrayList<WorldOfAdams> myPlanets = new ArrayList<WorldOfAdams>(); 
    myPlanets.add(new AllosimaniusSyneca()); 
    myPlanets.add(new BlagulonKappa()); 
    myPlanets.add(new Damogran()); 
    myPlanets.add(new Traal()); 

//Get current population for each of the planets
    for (int i=0; i<myPlanets.size(); i++) {
    myPlanets.get(i).getCurrentPopulation();
```

And each planet has its own set of instructions. There is Allosimanius Syneca, Blagulon Kappa, Damogran and Traal.

Instruction for Allosimanius Syneca are

```
/**
 * This class models the planet Allosimanius Syneca. On this planet travelers are not 
 *welcome. Anyone landing on the planet at any of the 3 spaceports is immediately put 
 *to work in the cinnamon mines. No one is ever allowed to leave.
 */
```

Based of the method of this planet it would appear that the current population would be set to 0 since no one is ever allowed to visit this planet but in the increase population I would need to reflect that there is an increase but that the traveler will go straight to the cinnamon mine. How can I implement this? I know that I need to create code that will increase population and then print statement showing that the increase in population goes "to the cinnamon mines". Do I put this code in the main?

The instructions for Blagulon Kappa:

```
 /***
 * All travelers who arrive on this planet are treated with kindness. They may stay as 
 * long as they like and leave whenever they like. However, they will not reveal the 
 *current population to anyone. All inquiries are ignored.
```

Based on this information I would need to print a statement reflecting that the population may increase but the output is "none of their business". Would this planet have a simple print statement and no code to increase population since the output isn't allowed to be known?

The instructions for Damogran:

```
/***
 * Damogran is a mostly peaceful planet that has completely run out of livable land. 
 *They do not allow anyone to visit the planet or leave it. Ever.
```

So for this planet I would set the current population at 0 and there is no increase in population.

And lastly the instruction for Traal:

```
/***
* 10% of the travelers arriving on this planet are immediately fed to the Ravenous 
* Bugblatter Beast. Survivors are allowed to come and go as they wish.
```

For this planet I would need to increase the population but divide that increase by 10% and print a statement with that remaining number that states "fed to Bugblatter Beast"

Just learning how to use interfaces and abstract classes and having a difficult time understanding how to implement all of these classes to run together and be able to give different results. Any help or guidance that you can give is much appreciated!!

Comment: In what variable are you storing the population? Why not just increase that variable?

Comment: Check your superclass, `WorldOfAdams`, it probably has a variable to store the `currentPopulation`. You'll want to increase that variable, probably `currentPopulation += populationIncrease`

Comment: The ability to increase a value implies that you are storing said value.  Add a class member to store the population.  add the increased ammount to the stored population.

Comment: As Miche said, you really didn't provide anywhere close to enough information to answer you sufficiently.

Comment: @NewbieGirl The reason Miche asked for the full text of your homework is because there isn't enough information here to help. There's a small chunk of code with no context, no superclass to help us determine how population is being stored, etc. Don't make people guess, and don't get snippy if we can't read your mind or figure out what your homework is supposed to be.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have edited my initial question to reflect the interface and base class.

Comment: @NewbieGirl It looks like there's a `WorldOfAdams` superclass that has some stuff in it, like the population, since it's common across all the planets. It's unclear if a planet can have multiple mines.

Comment: @DaveNewton none of the other planets have a mine. Just this one.

Comment: @NewbieGirl It's unclear what the question is. If all planets have a population then that should be reflected in the `WorldOfAdams` superclass. The difference for `AllosimaniusSyneca` is that if you try to leave you can't, so you can override that planet's behavior.

Comment: @DaveNewton updated my question to reflect more information.

Comment: @PatrickJAbarell updated my question to reflect more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't want to seem rude, I'll make a guess and suggest your Increase population function should look like this :

```
@Override
public int IncreasePopulation(int populationIncrease) {

    CinnamonMines CM = getCinnamonMines(); //must be defined somewhere in your code
    CM.IncreasePopulation(populationIncrease);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Im sorry that I was rude in return, it just seems like most people are rude whenever they make comments about homework questions. I really do appreciate your help!!

Comment: I actually understand what you mean, there is a sense of judgement on SO that can be frustrating and easy to fall into.
So you understand the idea of this function is that instead of increasing the population, since the people are instantly leaving for the Cinnamon Mines, you directly call the IncreasePopulation method of the mines.
Let me know if you can make that work for your exercise.

Comment: updated my question to reflect more information. This assignment has my head spinning!